# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript wont run more than once even with different keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using asp.net c#, I would like to pop up alert message more than once, I have this code at my code behind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "all_field_alert", scp1, true);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "all_field_alert2", scp1, true);
```

Even I have different keys, it won't fire the alert 2 times, what did I do wrong?

Thanks & Regards,

I have tried

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"), scp1, true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("X"), scp1, true);
```

but end up same, only fire once.

Comment: That seems to be related to your script, could you please include the content of the `scp1` variable and the resulting HTML in your question?

Comment: Try `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [Window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) function, only one instance of it can be displayed at a time, while the code you have tried executes two.

To have multiple pop-ups, better use the [window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method which comes with a callBack and when the callBack is executed, you can pop another one.

**DEMO**

[image]

```html
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

C# - Code Behind

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string scp1 = "if (window.confirm('ALERT 1')) { if (window.confirm('ALERT 2')) { alert('LAST ALERT'); } }";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"), scp1, true);
}
```

In case using Pop-up elements such as the Bootstrap Modal, you'll need to create multiple instances and display them all. By calling show() on one instance twice, it will not display two modal popups.